# How to disable the Spaces sliding animation in OS X?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speed up Spaces on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/35144/speed-up-spaces-on-mac-os-x)

I would like to disable the slide animation when switching between Spaces. Basically I just want the screen to change to the next workspace without any animation.

I can't find any settings for it in System Preferences. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-swoosh-animation-off -bool YES
killall Dock
```

Comment: This stopped working in 10.7, and at the moment Lion users seem to be stuck with those animations: [osx lion - How do you disable the window switch animation when switching spaces with Mission Control? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/315600/how-do-you-disable-the-window-switch-animation-when-switching-spaces-with-mission) and [osx - How can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion? - Apple - Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion)

Answer (score 3):

At this stage, it [does not](http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=80340) [appear to be possible](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1819527) [under Leopard](http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/99148-disable-spaces-slide-animation-in-leopard/). People have been looking since Leopard first came out, and if I'm not picking up anything via Google, I'm guessing it isn't out there.

I do not know whether or not it's possible in Snow Leopard.

Unfortunately, the best piece of advice I can give you is to use the [keyboard shortcuts](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/) to move the view (and your apps) between spaces.

Comment: John- Thanks for the info. I do use the shortcuts to switch between spaces, but it still plays the slide animation. Is there a way around it using the shortcuts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. :(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install DesktopManager: it's free and works on both Leopard and Snow Leopard: http://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=3463

It has configurable transitions/speeds/hotkeys and a menubar pager.

Answer (score -1):

defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-swoosh-animation-off -bool YES

Then killall Finder and you are set.

I think it's only for >= 10.6.5

Finally.

Comment: Doesn't work on newer versions.

Comment: I rolled back this answer. It's very poor and should be deleted. The edit doesn't even make sense. Killing the finder has nothing to do with a default write on Finder in any context.