# How do you disable the window switch animation when switching spaces with Mission Control?

Tags: osx-lion, osx-yosemite, osx-el-capitan, osx-spaces, mission-control

In Snow Leopard, I had the window switch animation disabled when I quick-key between spaces. Now that it's Mission Control in Lion, there's a long animation during which all my desktop icons disappear and I can't use anything. I'd really like to disable this, but [the old fix doesn't appear to work](https://superuser.com/questions/35144/speed-up-spaces-on-mac-os-x).

How can I disable this needless animation in OS X Lion or later?

Comment: If you use the 3-finger swipe on the trackpad, the animation can go much faster. But I'm usually using an external keyboard & mouse, and I agree that the animation for the keyboard shortcut is painfully slow.

Comment: Unfortunately I mostly use my mac in clamshell mode with an external keyboard, monitor and mouse.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion

Comment: I have the same problem and question. Found a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speed up OSX Spaces by reducing or eliminating the animation delay?](https://superuser.com/questions/35144/speed-up-osx-spaces-by-reducing-or-eliminating-the-animation-delay)

Comment: There is no reason to have a different version of this question for each version of OSX.

Answer (score 12):

You can disable the animations with [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com) (born [ReSpaceApp](http://switchstep.com/ReSpaceApp)). Just uncheck the **Use transitions** checkbox in TotalSpaces preferences.

Total Spaces integrates with Mission Control's multiple desktop system and adds extensive customisation, including disabling animations or adjusting the speed.

It's compatible with OS X 10.10 but requires disabling System Integrity Protection on OS X 10.11.

Comment: For me as well.  After almost a year, we finally have a solution!

Comment: great answer! None of other answers works for me, only this works!

Comment: those apps are not free, I can do this easily with ubuntu and I don't understand why we should pay for TotalSpaces

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255220/337005

Answer (score 6):

Change the delay when dragging windows or applications within Spaces.

Launch the Terminal and enter the following at the command line:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 0.1
```

The number on the end represents the wait time - the default is set to 0.75 (or 3/4 of a second), so 0.5 is half a second, 0.1 is a tenth of a second, and so on. If you use the above command and 0.1 you’ll get a near instant switching of spaces.

If you want to revert to the default setting, just specify it as so:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 0.75
```

Comment: I'll give this a vote because it is helpful, but it's still not a solution proper yet.

Comment: This doesn't work for me under Monterey.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the animation that shows up when you launch mission control with this

```
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -int 0; killall Dock
```

and undo with

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration; killall Dock
```

If you'd like to keep the animation, but speed it up, you can do this instead

```
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0.1; killall Dock
```

I don't know how to disable the annoying sliding animation when moving between spaces without using mission control, though--as was mentioned above, using ctrl+1, ctrl+2, ... does make that animation a lot faster.

Comment: Did not work on 10.10

Answer (score 2):

Does [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/25/disable-the-new-window-animation-in-mac-os-x-lion/) relate to your problem ?

It advocates this command :

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO
```

For desktop switching, I quote from [How can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion/19118#19118) :

> I've just noticed that doing Control+Number is noticeably faster than
>   Control+Arrow. It's still animated but it does complete the animation
>   in about half the time.
>
> Sadly, Mission Control hasn't yet been modified (or the secret
>   preferences to tweak it haven't yet been baked in or discovered.)
>
> You really have no choice other than staying on 10.6 or seeking an
>   alternate window manager like hyperspaces.

Comment: That pertains to the individual window animation, not desktop switching (aka virtual desktops).

Comment: Added some more stuff.

Comment: You can add all you want, but I won't accept it unless you answer the question.

Comment: Some questions have only negative answers. Your question may have been posted too early, and the full answer is not yet known. At this time, I can't do better than the above, but you have of course the right to wait for a better answer or accept none.