# How do I disable Mac OS X Spaces animation?

Tags: osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable the window switch animation when switching spaces with Mission Control?](https://superuser.com/questions/315600/how-do-you-disable-the-window-switch-animation-when-switching-spaces-with-mission)

Is there a way in Mac OS X to turn off the animation you see when switching [Spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_%28software%29)?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/315600/how-do-you-disable-the-window-switch-animation-when-switching-spaces-with-mission Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable the spaces animation in Lion.

What you can do is change the speed:

> defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -int 0; killall Dock

To revert that:

> defaults delete com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration; killall Dock

Just copy and paste those into Terminal to run those commands.

Read more about this [here on AD.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for may be in *[10.6: Disable Spaces workspace change animation Desktop](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110214074550501)*.

Comment: I tested that in Lion and it didn't work. Maybe it only works for previous versions of OSX?